# How to change size of points in R

Tags: r

I am creating a graph with many variables, so I have my x set, my y, the color, and the size for 4 different variables. However, I would like the size to be more pronounced as in, smaller points are even smaller and the bigger points get bigger so it's easier to digest. Here is my sample code. How can I change the point size?

```
ggplot(nyc)+
  aes(x=Food, y = Price, color =Service, size = Decor)+
  geom_point(aes(size = qsec))+
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'gold', high = 'forestgreen')+
  ggtitle("Relationship between Food, Price, Service, Decor, and East Indicator")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  facet_wrap(~East)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
+ scale_size(range = c(1,12))
```

to your ggplot. The smallest points will be of size 1, and the largest of size 12.

---

If your data is only positive and greater than 1, then if you want to make the size of points increase non-linearly with magnitude, you can add the non-linearity directly:

```
+ geom_point(size=12*(nyc$qsec^4 / max(nyc$qsec^4)))
```

Here the largest point will be of size 12 and the size will decay as a quartic for smaller points.